# Jquery - Add element continuously when value of input has been enter

Tags: jquery

Hei. I wanna make some invitation user. When I input on `<input type="email">` and click the button to add the email. The email what I input is 'move' to another element. I just make like this

HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
  <a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
  <select name="people_invited">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".add_people").click(function () {
  var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
  $("select[name='people_invited'] option").text(orang_yg_diinvite);
});
```

It just success. The email what I input on `<input type="email">` just move to inside `<option value=""></option>`, but when I input again on `<input type="email">`, email inside `<option value=""></option>` is replaced, not create new `<option value=""></option>`. How can I make the `<option value=""></option>` always create new one when I input from `<input type="email">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of:

```
 $("select[name='people_invited'] option").text(orang_yg_diinvite);
```

try:

```
$("select[name='people_invited']").append('<option>'+orang_yg_diinvite+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` instead of `text`.

```js
$(".add_people").click(function () {
        var orang_yg_diinvite = $("input[name='invite_people']").val();
        $("select[name='people_invited']").append('<option>' + orang_yg_diinvite + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" name="invite_people" placeholder="Invite someone">
  <a href="#!" class="add_people">Add People</a>
  <select name="people_invited">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```